# Convert A5325BE from hexadecimal to base 4

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I did it in two ways and I need help with both

1)

$$A_{16} = 22_{4}\\
5_{16} = 11_{4}\\
3_{16} = 3_{4}\\
2_{16} = 2_4\\
5_{16} = 11_4\\
B_{16} = 23_4\\
E_{16} = 32_4$$

The answer would be 221132112332. It's missing zeros on the 2 and the 3. What I don't understand is why this happens. When the base I am converting from is smaller than the one I am converting to this doesn't happen. Why is that?

2) 
$$E*16^0+B*16^1+5*16^2+2*16^3+3*16^4+5*16^5+A*16^6= \\
14*(4^2)^0+11*(4^2)^1+5*(4^2)^2+2*(4^2)^3+3*(4^2)^4+5*(4^2)^5+10*(4^2)^6=\\
14*4^0+0*4^1 +11*4^2+0*4^3+5*4^4+0*4^5+2*4^6+0*4^7+3*4^8+0*4^9+5*4^{10}+0*4^{11}+10*4^{12} = \\
22011030201102300_4$$

Clearly there's some issue with the zeros, probably the same as 1) but I don't understand it.

The right answer is 22110302112332

Answer (score 4):

This is really the fundamental reason it was necessary to invent the digit $0$.  In our system of orthography, we read two adjacent digits as providing multipliers for two consecutive powers of the base.  To simplify matters, let's convert the hex number $B3$ to base $4$.

Working from the right, we see

$$\begin{align}
3 \cdot 16^0 + 11 \cdot 16^1 &= 3 \cdot 4^0 + 11 \cdot 4^2\\ &= (0 \cdot 4^1 + 3) \cdot 4^0 + (2 \cdot 4+3) \cdot 4^2\\&=3 \cdot 4^0 + 0 \cdot 4^1 + 3 \cdot 4^2 + 2 \cdot 4^3.
\end{align}$$

Thus, the base $4$ representation is $2303_4$.  Does that help you see why the $0$s are necessary?

Comment: So ideally, when I have x*base^n where x is greater than the base, I should convert it to a number that's smaller than the base so there isn't trouble with zeros?

Comment: Every single time.  We do the same thing in base $10$.  That's why you don't have any numbers with, say, $13$ as a single digit.

Answer (score 0):

For the first method, remember you're not just exchanging digits; you have to keep the place values consistent.
For example, the $A$ is not just an $A,$ it's $A_{16} \times 16^6$ and is correctly replaced by $22_4 \times 4^{12}.$ So you *must* have $12$ base-four digits to the right of the $22.$
Likewise there must be $10$ base-four digits to the right of the leftmost $11$ in the base-four representation, whereas there are just $8$ base-four digits to the right of the $3.$ In order to make all those things true you need a $0$ between the $11$ and the $3.$

A simple way to enforce this is that every hexadecimal digit is replaced by two base-four digits, even if the digit on the left turns out to be $0.$

For the second method, I would always write the highest powers on the left and the lowest powers on the right. That's the order in which they occur in the base-$n$ representation. If you reverse the order then you might not reverse it back again correctly when you have to write the number in the new base.
For example you have two zeros at the end--how did that happen?

The other thing in the second method is that you have to remember that each power of four can only hold **one digit** in the final number. So if you have something like $14\times 4^0$ you have to carry into the $4^1$ digit.
That is, $0\times 4^1 + 14\times 4^0 = 3 \times 4^1 + 2\times 4^0,$ and you can use the second form to fill in the digits of the base-four number.

After all, if you add the base-ten numbers $29 + 37,$ where $2 + 3 = 5$ and $9 + 7 = 16,$ the answer is not $516,$ is it?